# Flash website + google indexing

Tags: html, flash, web, search-engine

This question has prolly been asked a zillion times and google is full of it but... I can't find nothing concrete.
So I got a Flash website that loads html files. In the html files is the content (text).
Google doesn't find the text (tried quoting a line for example to get precise search results).
So what must I do?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to sniff for Google and other crawlers and present a "text only" site. In fact, giving a link to a text-only version would be much better than anything else as text-based visitors could use it rather than your Flash version.

If you're just loading static HTML, this shouldn't be too difficult to compile together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Can you be a little bit more concrete though?
-"Sniff + Google". How do you do that?
-"Present a "text only" site". Where do I do that?
-"compile together" What you mean? Compiling html in the swf? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sniff with a server-side language to display different pages. There's plenty of resources on that out there. And no, not compiling HTML in SWF. I mean, arrange your HTML content into a static HTML layout that can be used by text browsers and crawlers.

Comment: Well I'm going to add the content of the html's in the primary html file. I'm gonna use the SWFObject to determine if a crawler is looking on the website, if it is; don't overwrite the content generated by the html files with the SWF.
Is this the right approach?